# Event on click with window.attachEvent

Tags: javascript, html

I am using code in javascript to generate a calendar:

Now I need that when I click on a day of a calendar, to be redirected on another page. Is there any way I can to that here in a js function?

Comment: `window.attachEvent` You have not needed that syntax in a decade.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load', go12(month,year), false);` <-- invalid, you are calling the function and assiging what go12 returns to the event listener. You basically just did. `go12(month,year);  window.addEventListener('load', undefined, false);`

Comment: It was a mistake when I copied some of the code. I updated the question with the code that I am using right now and that is functional. But is there any way I can add in this code that redirection to a page when I press a day of the calendar?

Comment: so add a click handler to the cell and set the window location to the new page.

Comment: I tried using this code: ```document.getElementById("try").onclick = function () {
 window.location.replace("./url");```                                   
 Where "try" is an id of a td tag but nothing happens

Comment: You use inline events everywhere for hovering, why not add the click there. If you want to go the eventListener way, you would need to use event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

If you need redirecting to another page - use `<a href="path/to/page"></a>`
You may use `display: block` to style it like a block